# Simplify multiple function for each IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a simple code that slides-in and out the toggled image using JQuery and CSS. I used multiple functions to hide/toggle the others when you click another image. Is there a way to minimize the usage of this?. Plus, when I click a different image for a third time, I have to double-click before it slides back. My code.. and its [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/166sb7ys/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#img1").toggle(
                    function () {
                        $("#img1").css({"transform": "translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px)"});
                        $("#img2").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                        $("#img3").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                    },
                    function () {
                        $("#img1").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                    }
            );
            $("#img2").toggle(
                    function () {
                        $("#img2").css({"transform": "translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px)"});
                        $("#img1").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                        $("#img3").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                    },
                    function () {
                        $("#img2").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                    }
            );
            $("#img3").toggle(
                    function () {
                        $("#img3").css({"transform": "translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px)"});
                        $("#img2").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                        $("#img1").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                    },
                    function () {
                        $("#img3").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                    }
            );
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .cardcont img {
            transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
        }
        .cardcont #img1 {
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            z-index:-1;
        }
        .cardcont #img2 {
             position:absolute;
             left:200px;
             top:0;
             z-index:-1;
         }
        .cardcont #img3 {
            position:absolute;
            left:400px;
            top:0;
            z-index:-1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cardcont">
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fokk9j.jpg" id="img1"/>
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fokk9j.jpg" id="img2"/>
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/fokk9j.jpg" id="img3"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `class` name rather than `ID`'s?

Comment: Example https://jsfiddle.net/166sb7ys/4/ using a class name will allow you to use one function to run it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shorty using `this` and `.not`..

**css** (added)

```
.cardcont img {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.active-image {
  transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px)!important;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    $('img').not(this).removeClass('active-image');
    $(this).toggleClass('active-image');
  });
});
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/98dxLy5c/

**note**

You will probably want to more specifically target the images, using `.cardcont img` as Vincent suggested is one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `.each()` function to achieve this like for instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".cardcont img").each(function(){              
            $(this).click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                  $(this).css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                }else{
                  $(".cardcont img").css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
                  $(this).css({"transform": "translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px)"});
                  $(this).addClass('active');                
                }
            });            
     });
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/166sb7ys/7/)

This way, you don't have to touch on your HTML structure.

**Docs:** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/